# How to get points X, Y coordinates from line angle?

Tags: algorithm, math, line, pseudocode, angle

So I have a 8x8 square. There is a line in it.

```
Line size == 8 angle == 0.
```

One of line points is always on one of the top corners.

What would be a formula to retrieve  points coordinates where line crosses borders of square? (positive angle means one of line points is 0, 0. negative 0, 8 )

What would be math formula for each of coordinates points? (in pseudo code if possible)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
line_end_x = line_start_x + cos(angle)*line_length

line_end_y = line_start_y + sin(angle)*line_length
```

if your line crosses a vertical edge:

```
intersection_x = edge_x
intersection_y = line_start_y + (intersection_x - line_start_x) * tan(angle)
```

if your line crosses a horizontal edge:

```
intersection_y = edge_y
intersection_x = line_start_x + (intersection_y - line_start_y) * tan(angle-pi/4)
```

EDIT: corrected